# Android wear watch face rejected - "basic functionality"?

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, watch-face-api

I submitted my first android wear watch face to the Play store last night, but it got rejected. The reason in the email was simply:

> Eligibility issues:
>
> -Basic functionality of your app does not work as described. Be sure to test your app on a variety of different Android Wear devices and
>   configurations.
>
> Please refer to the following developer pages for details:
>   https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html
>   https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html

How can I find out more? It works fine on my own watch, and a friend with a different watch tried it and it was also fine. I've tried it on the emulator with a few other screen sizes, and it works there too. I don't see anything in the developer console that lets me see what tests they did that failed, so I don't know what to do to fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after submitting via the "hey, you rejected me in error" link, I got another rejection email, but this one had the magic line "Crashes on ASUS Zenwatch".

Some googling led me to discover the Asus uses "Low-bit ambient mode". I then discovered in my Huawei developer options I can force that. Did so and hey presto- it crashes!
At least I have a stack trace now and can fix it.

Comment: Can you please tell me what did you do to support "low-bit ambient mode"? And did they accept your watch face?

Comment: Yes, they did once I fixed that. 
To fix it, I simply had some checks for if I was in low bit ambient (there's a bool already in the sample code IIRC) and update properties on my Paint objects accordingly (disabling anti aliasing was the key one).
Worth reading https://developer.android.com/design/wear/watchfaces.html#SpecialScreens and https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidWear/comments/2qb3ia